# How do I make my container sync the files I make? (docker)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm making a web application using Laravel 7 but I want to develop it in docker, but when I am using my container, the container files are not synchronized with the ones that are shown in the text editor, how can I solve that?

The files that are not synchronized are, for example, the migrations or the composer.json, that is, when I install a package through composer, those changes are not reflected in the text editor

I've tried to put `./:/var/www/html` in docker-compose.yml but I get an error when I run it. `Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html /artisan online 18`

Next, I provide my dockerfile and my docker compose.

Dockerfile

```
FROM composer:1.10.22 as build_stage

LABEL maintainer="Me"
COPY . /src
ADD .env.example /src/.env
WORKDIR /src
RUN composer install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN php artisan key:generate


FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
ENV \
  BUILD_PACKAGES="build-base curl-dev linux-headers" \
  SQLITE_PACKAGES="zlib-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev postgresql postgresql-dev sqlite sqlite-libs sqlite-dev nano php7-gd php7-mysqli php7-zlib php7-curl"
RUN apk update &&  apk add $BUILD_PACKAGES && apk add $SQLITE_PACKAGES

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN set -ex \
  && apk --no-cache add \
  postgresql-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

COPY --from=build_stage /src /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

EXPOSE 5000

COPY ./run.sh /tmp
RUN chmod +x /tmp/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/run.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

networks:
  project-net:

volumes:
  project-datastore:

services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    volumes:
      - project-datastore:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - project-net
    ports:
      - "25432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  project:
    build:
      context: ./
    image: project:latest
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/app
      - ./public:/var/www/html/public
      - ./routes:/var/www/html/routes
      - ./resources:/var/www/html/resources
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - project-net
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres-db:5432/db
```

run.sh

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Mexico_City /etc/localtime
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```

Comment: Have you shelled into the container to see if/what files are bound into the container? (what files exist in there) `docker exec -it project bash -l`

Comment: @ScottAnderson Yes, of course, the files exist in the container, but the files that are outside the container are not synchronized. For example, if I want to edit the files in my word processor, they do not have the same content as those in the container, for example, I edit the composer. json in the container and hi is changed but in a word processor the changes do not come out.

Comment: When you say Word Processor, what do you mean? Please tell me you are using an IDE

Comment: @ScottAnderson Visual Studio Code but that is not the problem, rather that the files are not synchronized, but only some for example the migrations the composer.json

Comment: When you run the docker-compose as-is, does Laravel work? Or does Laravel not run both when you have a bind mount of `./:/var/www/html` and without?

Comment: @ScottAnderson Laravel doesn't work if I add ```./:/var/www/html``` I get error ```Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): error opening stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/html/artisan at line 18 Fatal error: require(): Failed to open required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib /php') in /var/www/html /craft online 18```

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question, I am asking - does it work without that line?

Comment: @ScottAnderson yes but as I say, what I want to be synchronized, it doesn't

Comment: According to this https://medium.com/@jonsbun/why-need-to-be-careful-when-mounting-single-files-into-a-docker-container-4f929340834, it could be that VSCode is creating temporary files? I am not sure, but you could go down the route of using the remote-development extension for containers as mentioned in the summary

Comment: As a test though, can you please edit the files in an editor like nano or vim and see if the file gets updated in the container, just to eliminate IDE issues?